# How to block sending mails?

Tags: sendmail

I want to block specific user from sending emails. I tried doing these things which did not help:

1. Commented user in `/etc/passwd`
2. Wrote `passwd -l user` and restarted `sendmail` service.

User can't receive mails - that's OK, but they still may send mails. I use Sendmail (port 25) and Dovecot (port 110 POP3).

Any ideas to block a user from sending mails?

Comment: The purported duplicate question is about a Posfix system.  This question is about, as it says, a Sendmail system.  It is not the same answer for both.

Comment: *Then it is not dupe.*

Answer (score 1):

In Sendmail you can add this user to the `/etc/mail/access` database file (`access.db`) to disallow them from sending emails:

Put their address in the file `/etc/mail/access`:

```
user@my-domain.com REJECT
```

Then rebuild it:

```
$ makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access
```

**NOTE:** From what I remember you may have to put several permutations of their email address in this file to stop them. so things like `user@localhost`, etc.

I do not have a sendmail setup handy, but you can typically use a `Makefile` command that's provided in newer implementations of `sendmail`.

For more controlling the sending/receiving via Sendmail you can do more specific controls like this in this file:

```
To:a1@server.vikas.com       REJECT           # Reject a1 user from recieving mails
From:a1@server.vikas.com     REJECT           # Reject a1 user from sending mails
```

#### References

- [How to enable/disable user's access to email (sendmail)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/how-to-enable-disable-user%27s-access-to-email-sendmail-752224/)

Comment: Is it necessary to rebuild it? I am a little frightened to use makemap command

Comment: I seem to remember that restarting the sendmail service did this as well. But yeah you typically have to rebuild these files in order for sendmail to use them. BTW I just reinstalled sendmail on CentOS 7 and it does still come with a `make` command, so you should be able to run that if your setup has it. If you're pensive to do this, back up the whole `/etc/mail` dir 1st.

Comment: Good old sendmail...I prefered to deal with it editing .mc files...it would be interesting understanding the problem of the user, blocking users in sendmail wont prevent users/malware scripts form sending email/spam via TCP/25 if the infra-structure allows it.

Comment: @slm, may I only restart sendmail service after REJECTING user in access file? Will it help?

Comment: @itdev - my suggestion was to try doing a restart after adding REJECT entry to see if it triggers a rebuild of `access.db`, but I'm 90% sure that you have to rebuild these manually using either `rehash` or the `make` command.

Comment: I am frightened to do it on working system. What is the meaning of makemap hash? What does that command exactly do? It builds /etc/access file from /etc/acces.db ???

Comment: @itdev - it merely rebuilds the `.db` files. These are binary forms of the text files. It's completely safe to do this in this directory, you can back up the existing `access.db` file, do the `makemap hash` of the explicit file and restart sendmail. If there's any issue, put the original back in and do another restart. http://www.linuxweblog.com/sendmail-accessdb-example